# Drawing a cone surface in general equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, draw

How can I draw a cone surface in the general equation of:

```
ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dxy+exz+fyz+gx+hy+iz+k=0
```

in Matlab please?

Comment: http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html

Comment: it needs to define the vectors of x, y, and z. How do you define them based on the equation I provided?

Comment: http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html This should help, read it then ask a more precise question if you don't understand.

Comment: It has actually same issue. If you check the examples in the page you sent me, you will see that in all of them Z is as a function of x and y (Z = f(X,Y);). This is while in the equation I listed above, we don't know z as a function x and y. So if for drawing a surface, we necessarily do not have to have Z = f(X,Y);, then please give me an example. OR if we can change the above equation so that we have Z = f(X,Y);, then please explain or plot this equation: -11.56x^2-10.24y^2-90.53z^2+16.43xy+66.66xz-33.67yz-19156.33x+7731.95y+50429.65z-6899727.01=0. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody else was looking for this: my question was duplicate of

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15100406/3179989

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer to your question (but it's too bulky for a comment),  hopefully it can help you to proceed. Regarding your concern about z=f(x,y), you can get it solving a simple quadratic equation for z:

```
clear all;
a = - 90.53;
b = @(x,y)(66.66*x - 33.67*y  + 50429.65);
c = @(x,y)( -11.56*x.^2 - 10.24*y.^2 + 16.43*x*y - 19156.33*x  + 7731.95*y  - 6899727.01);
D = @(x,y)(b(x,y).^2 - 4 * a * c(x,y));
z1  = @(x,y)( ( -b(x,y) + sqrt(D(x,y) )) / (2*a) );
z2  = @(x,y)( ( -b(x,y) - sqrt(D(x,y) )) / (2*a) );
```

Note that for some (x,y) your D<0 and z1 and z2 will be complex, these points correspond to space outside your cone. You can select relevant subspace like

```
xD = -100:100;
yD = arrayfun(@(x)(fzero(@(y)(D(x,y)),0.0)),xD);
```

Now you'll need to use define X,Y,Z matrices and use surf to plot it. Please let me know if that works, otherwise i'll give another try later.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I found the solution and posted its link.